# Finding girth using BFS for a Digraph

Tags: graph-theory, digraphs

So I am having some trouble finding the girth for the following [Digraph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfbG7.jpg)
[image]

I am required to use BFS to find the girth, but I am lost in how to find it.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: That graph appears to be acyclic. Are you looking for a general BFS algorithm to find the girth of a graph?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no girth or circle in the graph.
Second, BFS cannot be used to find circle in graph.

If you want to find the girth, here is the way:

(In the directed graph)
1. Using DFS to find circles.

2. For each circle, remove one edge from one vertex U to another vertex V.
3. Calculating the shortest path between U and V, using dijkstra or floyd.
4. Adding the removed edge to the shortest path. Thus, get the length of circles.
5. Find the shortest one.